# Discord js and mysql

Tags: discord.js

I try insert to database:
con.query(`UPDATE ${'s' + message.guild.id} SET xp = ${xp}, username = ${message.author.username} WHERE userID = ${message.author.id}`);

but
**Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Steve123' in 'field list'**
Only username doesnt work! Please help.

Mysql:
username - varchar(50) - latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: I'd watch out using this way of inserting strings in a database query as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: As Sjored said, I wouldn't use this method to insert data into a query as it is vulnerable to a SQL injection. I would recommend escaping your string then I would stripcslash your string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
con.query(
`UPDATE ? SET xp=?, username=? WHERE userID=?`,
[message.guild.id, xp, message.author.username, message.author.id],
(err, results) => {
    // handle stuff here
}
)
```

I don't really know why your table name is variable though, usually your table name would be `guilds` or the likes. Also, when inserting values in MySQL, you should use single quotes, you aren't using those, which is probably why you're getting that error.

`username=${message.author.username}` translates to `username=username` when it should be `username='username'`.